# Why am I getting null values when submitting a form after editing some values with JS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, asp.net-mvc

I have a form with some inputs that are filled from the result of an AJAX request. When I submit the form I get only `null` on the back-end. I tried to submit the values without editing it and it works

this is my java script code

```
editPayment = function() {
  if ($('#entrytransId').val() != '') {
    if ($('#entryReceiptTypesselect').val() == "1") {
      $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "@Url.Action("GetInvoiceNumber", "Payment")",
        data: {transId: $('#entrytransId').val()},
        success: function(response) {
          if (response.invNo == 0) {
            window.location.reload();
          } else {
            $('#reciptNo').val(response.invNo);
            $('#enteryAmt').val(response.Amt);
            $('#entrytransId').attr("disabled", "true");
            $('#enteryhide').show(500);
          }
        },
        error: function(reponse) {
          window.location.reload();
        }
      });
    }
  }
```

This is Exactly My HTML Form with inputs I have tried more times and its failures
but when I deleted the javascript function and fill the data manually its works

```html
<form action="/Payment/EditPayment" id="MF" method="post">                                    
<div class="row">
<div class="col-md-2">
   <label class="form-control">Receipt Type</label>
</div>
<div class="col-md-8">
<select class="form-control" id="entryReceiptTypesselect" 
name="entryReceiptTypes" required="true"><option value="">-Choose</option>
<option value="1">MoF</option>
<option value="2">Zakah</option>
<option value="3">Tax</option>
<option value="4">Other Taxs</option>
<option value="5">M & S</option>
</select>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label class="form-control">Trans Id</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-3">
        <input required="" type="number" class="form-control" id="entrytransId" name="entrytransId">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-2" hidden="" id="btnHidden">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary legitRipple" onclick="editPayment()">check</button>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-control" id="lblinvoice">reciptNo</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input required="" type="number" name="reciptNo" class="form-control" id="reciptNo">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row" hidden="" id="enteryhide">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-control">enteryAmt</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <input required="" type="number" value="0" name="enteryAmt" class="form-control" id="enteryAmt">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-control">E15 userName</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input required="" type="text" class="form-control" id="userName" name="userName">
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label class="form-control">password</label>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-8">
            <input required="" type="password" class="form-control" id="password" name="password">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<br>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
        <input type="submit" value="submit" class="btn btn-block btn-success legitRipple" id="enterysubmit">
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: Are the `#receiptNo`, `#enteryAmt` etc fields actually *within* the `form` element which you submit?

Comment: Do `response.invNo` and `response.Amt` have values? Or are they null or empty?

Comment: Yes, and I tried to submit values without editing it and it's works

Comment: Yes response.invNo and response.Amt have values and not null

Comment: Besides, we see that you either prefix your controls with "entry" or "entery". Is it a typo?

Comment: There could be a mismatch with the HTML control / JS - can you include the `<form>` and *relevant* HTML inputs?

Comment: @freedomn-m I did

Comment: Is it all the fields or just `entrytransId` ?  If you *disable* a field, it will not be included in the form POST `$('#entrytransId').attr("disabled", "true");`  (apologies for not noticing this sooner)

Comment: oookaaay , you are right, i have another function `onselectChange()` is disabled all inputs , i tried  `$('#entrytransId').attr("disabled", "true");` and its works well , thanks @freedomn-m

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is not with setting the values via javascript/jquery, but specifically with setting the inputs to *disabled*.

```
$('#entrytransId').attr("disabled", "true");
```

when an input is set to `disabled`, it is not included (it is excluded) from the form's POST, so will appear as `null` in the server-side code.

You can:
- not set them to disabled (will affect your UX)
- enable them just before POST (icky)
- use hidden fields

MVC does this for checkboxes, so you can copy that idea here:

```
<input type='text' name='entryid' />
<input type='hidden' name='entryid' />
```

POST uses the input's `name` field, not its `id`, so it's ok to have multiple inputs with the same name.

POST will then use the *first input that is not disabled* (so don't put the hidden one first...)

Then just update the jquery to apply the value to both inputs (if you also want it shown in the UI) rather than by id, eg:

```
$("name[entryid]").each(function() { $(this).val(newvalue); });
```

(other ways to set this may be better, not checked if `.val()` will apply to all, likely only applies to the first)

Answer (score 0):

The proplem was on `$('#entrytransId').attr("disabled", "true");` 
 i have another function `onselectChange()` is disabled all inputs , i tried `$('#entrytransId').attr("disabled", "true");` and its works well